# Loop in SQL query for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql

```
SELECT
   name as [dbname]
FROM
   sys.databases
   -- for each [dbname]
   --update @[dbname] [dbo].[tb_Setting] -- this is the loop I need help with
   SET
     currentvalue = 'Powered by WaqarAttari'
   WHERE
     Title = 'MyFooter' and currentvalue = 'Powered by WaqarAttari'
```

**I want to help on this section**

```
 -- for each [dbname]
 --update @[dbname] [dbo].[tb_Setting] -- this is the loop I need help with
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the undocumented sp_msforeachdb procedure

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
USE ?
IF DB_ID() > 4 --ignore system databases

  update [dbo].[tb_Setting]
  SET
  currentvalue = ''Powered by WaqarAttari''
  WHERE
  Title = ''MyFooter'' and currentvalue = ''Powered by WaqarAttari''
  '
```